# Bounding expected value and variance

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, variance

Bounding Mean Absolute Deviation from the Mean using Variance
Let $X$ be a real random variable with $E[X] = 0$. Let $a = E[|X|]$ and $b = Var(X)$.
(a) Find the best possible upper bound on $a$ in terms of $b$.
(b) Find the best possible upper bound on $b$ in terms of $a$.
(c) Demonstrate that your bounds are tight by constructing a random variable $X_{a,b}$ for each pair
$(a, b)$ satisfying the inequalities from the previous parts.

Attempt at a solution:

By the definition of $var(X)$,
$$b = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$$
Since $E[X] = 0$, this reduces to
$$b = E[X^2]$$
By Jensen's Inequality,
$$b \ge (E[|X|])^2$$
$E[|X|] = a$; therefore
$$b \ge a^2$$
$a\le\sqrt b$ which gives a best possible upper bound on $a$ in terms of $b$.

However, I am unsure how to find a best possible upper bound on $b$ in terms of $a$. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the editing improvements.

Comment: There is no upper bound for $b$ in terms of $a$. The question is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help on the second part.  Is the upper bound on a in terms of b which I derived correct for part one?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.